# DOMDocument xpath query on img by conditions

Tags: xml, xpath, domdocument

this is 2 lines of mycode from my function, i was wondering whether it was possible to query the images so that it gets images greater than 200px in width or height 200px..

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $htmlget);
       $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//img/@src" );
```

Comment: I'm wondering how your input document looks like!

Answer (score 4):

Try this query:

```
//img[@width > 200 or substring-before(@width, 'px') > 200 
    or @height > 200 or substring-before(@height, 'px') > 200]/@src
```

It will return `@src` of images with height or width > 200.

This XPath

```
//img[(not(@width) and not(@height)) or (@width > 200 or @height > 200)]/@src
```

will select all `img` **without** width and height (e.g.: `<img src="src"/>`, but not `<img src="src" width="100"/>` **or** which have `width` or `height` > 200.

Comment: thanks.. cant i make it more faster? its takes 10 secs to get images from some urls

Comment: @dean, It depends. Firstly, maybe download of this HTMLs takes the longest part of time?

Comment: @dean, Also, if in `img` height and width are specified only in this format like: `width="500"`, i.e. without suffix `px`, you can simply write: `//img[@width > 200 or @height > 200]/@src`

Comment: @dean, Also you can specify more appropriate path to images, e.g.: `/html/body/div[@id = 'divID']//img[@width > 200 or @height > 200]/@src`.

Comment: oh i see.. but if there are no width or height, can i alter the query like adding an if or soemthing.. because now, its missing out all images without widths and height params

Comment: @dean, In other words you need image without width and height or image with width or height > 200?